# CSS with background image and a little content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a background image where I am going to overlay a testimonial in it near the lower right.  I am having a hard time to get this to work properly with responsive design.  So I have an image that is 930x454 which I want to show the entire image.  I tried to set a min-width and min-height and can get it to work but when I shrink the window it then is wider then the screen.  Ideally I would want the image to not exceed 100% width of screen size.  The content is only 3 sentences so it does not even come close to taking up 930x454.

Do I need to write a resize function or is there a fairly easy css solution to this.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: **[Long story short](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two key concepts are important here: *positionin*g (in this case *relative* on the parent and *absolute* on the text box), and *background-size*. I'll leave it to you to Google those.

```css
.background {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/930/454/nature');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="text">Some text.</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/umuyzcvj/)

Comment: To me, anyway, firing a code snippet at an OP isn't overly helpful IMHO.

Comment: I don't intend to write a book on basic HTML in response to such a vague question (which will probably be closed shortly anyway). Feel free.

Comment: TBH I'm not even 100% sure what you're doing with reference to your answer, otherwise I would at least try to explain it.

Comment: This is just what i was looking for.  I was not doing the positioning which is why i think I couldn't get it to work.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score -1):

no need for any js just type your desired width in (%) i.e. `width: 100%;` it will work fine and do give some height as when width shrink the height will also shrink

Answer (score -1):

Use a meta tag code to get device width and bind it to content. Add it to your header. Don't forget the html tag brackets.

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"

Set the image to 100 percentage if you want it that way. The above code should keep all things responsive.